# What's the difference between $(-x)^2, -x^2$ and $-(x)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(-x)^2$ is definately equal to $(-1)^2(x)^2$, right?

But $-(x)^2$ and $-x^2$ are confusing me, do they mean $-(x^2)$ or do they mean $(-1)^2(x)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the unary $-$ has lower priority than exponentiation, convention$^\ast$ says
$$-(x)^2 = -x^2 = -(x^2) = -x\cdot x$$
The parentheses just clarify the meaning here. In the expression $(-x)^2 = (-x)\cdot(-x) = x^2$ they are essential.
This convention is very similar to the way that
$$3-2\cdot 4 = 3 - (2\cdot 4)$$
must be handled.

$^\ast$ some programming languages have a different convention (for example [Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=226785)), but generally this is the standard unless stated otherwise, such as in a language specification. [See this wikipedia section on exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Exceptions_to_the_standard)

Comment: Why would you write $-(x)^2$ rather than $-(x^2)$ ?

Comment: @DanielV The OP specifically asked for the meaning of $-(x)^2$, but I'll add this form as well.

Comment: I have to disagree with your answer.  "Academic convention says" might be correct, but software convention (which is more important to many people, myself among them) is frequently the opposite.

Comment: @DanielV Can you provide evidence? I don't see any discrepancy between standard programming languages and academic convention. (Note that stack-based languages use polish notation so they are to be excluded from this)

Comment: I attempted to actually, but https://tryhaskell.org/ is down for me.  Also if you have LibreOffice Calc, which is fairly standard opensource spreadsheet software, try typing $\text{= -2^4}$ in one of the cells.  There are plenty of secretaries who will care more about spreadsheet convention than paywalled math paper repository convention.

Comment: @DanielV Interesing. Excel (I don't like LibreOffice at all) has the same behaviour, but I wouldn't call it a programming language. Looking into haskell, since that's actually a real example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21017/discussion-between-alexr-and-danielv).

Answer (score 0):

$(-x)^2=(-x)(-x)=(-1)^2(x)^2=x^2$

$-(x)^2=-(x\cdot x)=-x^2$

$-x^2=-(x^2)$ as shown above

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the medium you are using.  Given that exponentiation is evaluated before subtraction by convention (probably from the study of polynomials), there become 2 competing design decisions:

- That subtraction and negation are evaluated with the same priority
- That unary operators are universally evaluated before binary operators

Most academic publications will use the first convention, that $-x^2 = -(x^2)$.

A lot of software (Haskell, some spreadsheet software) will use the second convention so $-x^2 = (-x)^2$.